# Binomial expansion within a taylor series

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

If I know that there is a Taylor series for a function

$f\left(x\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}c_i\left(x-x_0\right)^i$

am I always justified in saying that this can be re-expressed as a series of the form

$f\left(x\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_i x^i$

where $b_i$ may depend on the $c_i$ and $x_0$?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is no, that conclusion is not always justified. 
$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ has a Taylor series expansion about $x_0 =1$, which can be gotten from the series $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{i=o}^{\infty} x^i$. But $f$ has no expansion about $x_0 = 0$, because it does not exist there.

If $0$ is in the interval of convergence for your original function, I believe the conclusion would be justified.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes.

If we say that
$$f_n(x)=\sum_{i=0}^nc_i(x-x_0)^i$$
then we can expand this via the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) using [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). Therefore, every term of $c_i(x-x_0)^i$ can be expressed as
$$c_i(x-x_0)^i=c_i\sum_{j=0}^ia_jx^j$$
where $a_j$ represents the binomial coefficients and terms involving multiplication by some powers of $x_0$. Substituting this into our original equation gives
$$f_n(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n\left(c_i\sum_{j=0}^ia_jx^j\right)$$
which can then of course be written in the form of some series
$$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^nb_kx^k$$
where the $b_k$s take all of the above coefficients into account.

*However*, as [Van Latimer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2333866/170257) pointed out, this is *not* the same as expanding $f(x)$ as a MacLaurin series around $x=0$. Plugging $x=0$ into $f_n(x)$ will merely get you the value of $f(x_0)$, in the approximation - not the value of $f(x_0)$, because $f$ may not be defined at $x=0$. Your answer may bear no relation to the actual value of $f(x)$ at $x=0$ - if there is one.

Comment: The upper limit on your first, third and last sums should be $\infty$.  More important, you don't take convergence considerations into account.   If the third sum is not convergent, then you can't re-arrange the terms as you suggest.